# Немного запутался с типами при создании функции которая принимает строку в виде массива

Tags: c++

Не могу понять где наапортачил. Только начал изучать С++ и предомной стоит такая задача, найти количество букы "а" в строке которая передаётся функции и вывести количество этих букв. Код значит выглядит вот так.

```
char str(char *str[]) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(str) / sizeof(*str); i++) {
        if (str[i] == "a") {
            j++;
        }
    }


    return j;
}


Вызов функции в main.
cout << str("saassssasasasass") << endl;
```

Так вот когда вызываю функцию, VS выдаёт вот такую ошибку. Вчём проблемма? И ещё вопрос зачем нужны звёздочки `char *str[]` и  `sizeof(str) / sizeof(*str)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тут всё неправильно. аргумент не строка, а массив указателей на строку. и sizeof не считает длину строки, нужно strlen.
Рекомендую посмотреть исходный код strcmp. Может и появятся идеи.

Comment: [pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer)

Answer (score 0):

```
int str(const char *str) 
{
    int count = 0;

    for(; *str; str++) 
        if (*str == 'a') ++count;

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка первая : в функцию передаёте строку, а принимаете как массив строк.

```
char str(char *str[]) {
```

надо так:

```
char str(char const * str) {
```

Ошибка вторая : вы сравниваете букву со строкой:

```
if (str[i] == "a") {
```

надо так:

```
if (str[i] == 'a') {
```

Код `sizeof(str) / sizeof(*str)` это кто-то что-то ляпнул. Хотели вычислить количество букв в зависимости от размера структуры и размера элементов.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(str) / sizeof(*str); i++) {
```

для строки нужно так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
```